# How I make this faster?

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I have a multiindex like this :

```
MultiIndex([(      ('DDB_1_1', 'DDB651140'),    ('DDB_2_26776', 'DDB651140')),
        (      ('DDB_1_10', 'DDB16450'),     ('DDB_2_20431', 'DDB16450')),
        (   ('DDB_1_1000', 'DDB651142'),   ('DDB_2_107596', 'DDB651142')),
        (   ('DDB_1_1000', 'DDB651142'),     ('DDB_2_9414', 'DDB651142')),
        (('DDB_1_1000000', 'DDB651144'), ('DDB_2_1002429', 'DDB1322404')),
        (('DDB_1_1000000', 'DDB651144'),  ('DDB_2_997810', 'DDB1322404')),
        (('DDB_1_1000000', 'DDB651144'),  ('DDB_2_998338', 'DDB1322404')),
        ( ('DDB_1_991985', 'DDB651144'), ('DDB_2_1002429', 'DDB1322404')),
        ( ('DDB_1_991985', 'DDB651144'),  ('DDB_2_997810', 'DDB1322404')),
        ( ('DDB_1_991985', 'DDB651144'),  ('DDB_2_998338', 'DDB1322404')),
        ...
        (('DDB_1_999965', 'DDB1321092'),  ('DDB_2_995355', 'DDB1321092')),
        (('DDB_1_999975', 'DDB1321098'), ('DDB_2_1006903', 'DDB1321098')),
        (('DDB_1_999981', 'DDB1321100'),  ('DDB_2_456110', 'DDB1321100')),
        (('DDB_1_999983', 'DDB1321101'), ('DDB_2_1100746', 'DDB1321101')),
        (('DDB_1_999983', 'DDB1321101'), ('DDB_2_1112598', 'DDB1321101')),
        (('DDB_1_999983', 'DDB1321101'), ('DDB_2_1383889', 'DDB1321101')),
        (('DDB_1_999983', 'DDB1321101'), ('DDB_2_1392811', 'DDB1321101')),
        (('DDB_1_999985', 'DDB1321103'), ('DDB_2_1005614', 'DDB1321103')),
        (('DDB_1_999985', 'DDB1321103'), ('DDB_2_1007716', 'DDB1321103')),
        (('DDB_1_999992', 'DDB1863510'),  ('DDB_2_995209', 'DDB1863510'))],
       length=815798)
```

I wrote this function to merge the two dfs

```
def patientdf(df1, df2, 
          eid1, dbid1,
          eid2, dbid2,
          r = 1 , namedf1 = 'left', namedf2 = 'right'):

    left = df1.loc[(slice(None),['{}'.format(eid1),'{}'.format(dbid1)]), :]
    left.insert(0,'local_index', r)
    left.insert(0,'df_source', namedf1)
    right = df2.loc[(slice(None), ['{}'.format(eid2), '{}'.format(dbid2)]), :]
    right.insert(0,'local_index', r)
    right.insert(0,'df_source', namedf2)
    left = left.reset_index()
    right = right.reset_index()
    combb = left.append(right, ignore_index = True)
    return combb
```

then for loop to match every records

```
patientdf0to10 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(ECMmatch[0:1000])):
    patient = patientdf(ub94, ub95, 
                  ECMmatch[i][0][0], ECMmatch[i][0][1],
                  ECMmatch[i][1][0], ECMmatch[i][1][1],
                  r = i, namedf1 = 'ub94', namedf2 = 'ub95')
    patientdf0to10= patientdf0to10.append(patient, ignore_index = True)
```

Then remove the duplicate

```
patientdf0to10.set_index('local_index').drop_duplicates()
```

The for loop is very slow and I have more than 2M rows and will do the same for other 24 df. Time for first 100 records is 5.53 s ± 62.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each). I try to just match on first Id (which I don't prefer) and the time went down to 3.56 s ± 33.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) still slow!

Comment: it would help (us help you) if you could boil your question down to the crux of the matter (simplify to the essence) and provide a minimal example. As it stands, it is quite hard to infer what you are trying to do.